# stored procedure with IN & OUT parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hope everyone is doing well !

Need help on stored procedure. Getting following error while creating the procedure. Any help is well appreciated.

> error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE regi_email (IN email VARCHAR(255), counti
>   OUT INT)
>
> BEGIN
>
> ' at line 3

MY Procedure is as below:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE hsiedwzw_booking

CREATE PROCEDURE regi_email (IN email VARCHAR(255), counti OUT INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE bContinue INTEGER;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO bContinue FROM parent_reg_email WHERE reg_email =email;

    IF bContinue=0;

THEN SET @counti=1;

    ELSE SELECT COUNT(*) INTO bContinue FROM ets_bookings WHERE c_email =email;

         IF bContinue=0;

         SET @counti=2;


         ELSE SET @counti=3;

END IF;

END
$$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in this line need to change like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE regi_email (IN email VARCHAR(255),OUT counti  INT)
```

**Edit:**

```
#DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`  is for your server ;;

USE hsiedwzw_booking;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `activeFor_accounthead`(IN email VARCHAR(255),OUT  counti INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE bContinue INTEGER;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO bContinue FROM parent_reg_email WHERE reg_email =email;

    IF bContinue=0;

THEN SET @counti=1;

    ELSE SELECT COUNT(*) INTO bContinue FROM ets_bookings WHERE c_email =email;

         IF bContinue=0;

         SET @counti=2;


         ELSE SET @counti=3;

END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi addy. Thanks for your answer however I have tried that too but getting the same error :(